# Matching inverse of multi line regex pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have the following regex in notepad++, which will find a line starting with "BGADD" and, if applicable, all subsequent lines that start with "+". This match works and I can use replace (with a zero length string) to remove these blocks of text from my document.

***Regex:***

```
^BGADD.*$(\R|\z)(^[+].*$(\R|\z))*
```

What I would like to do however is match and remove any blocks of text that are the opposite of this, such that I am left with only what matches the pattern.

I have tried combinations of positive/negative lookarounds but am failing to come up with something that works- possible becase the lookaround must be fixed length?
Thanks in advance for any help. I have tried numerous searches and have attempted to implement various things that I have read on similar threads, but have not got there yet.

***The data I am working with:***

```
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+          91016   91017   9
+          91024   91025   9
BGSET   10001002100001071000
+           1011    1012    
+           1019    1020    
BGADD       1000100010011000
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+       19001006290010013900
BGSET   20001001200001012000
+           1011    1012    
SOMETHINGELSE  3000100230000
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+       19001006290010013900
BGSET   30001003300001033000
BGSET   50001001500001035000
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+       19001006290010013900
DIFFERENTTHING   19001001190
+           1011    1012    
+           1019    1020    
BGSET   19001002190001071900
BGADD       1000100010011000
```

What it looks like if I replace with blank string on the regex:

```
BGSET   10001002100001071000
+           1011    1012    
+           1019    1020    
BGSET   20001001200001012000
+           1011    1012    
SOMETHINGELSE  3000100230000
BGSET   30001003300001033000
BGSET   50001001500001035000
DIFFERENTTHING   19001001190
+           1011    1012    
+           1019    1020    
BGSET   19001002190001071900
```

***What I am aiming for (i.e. the inverse):***

```
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+          91016   91017   9
+          91024   91025   9
BGADD       1000100010011000
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+       19001006290010013900
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+       19001006290010013900
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+       19001006290010013900
BGADD       1000100010011000
```

Comment: You could use `^(?!BGADD|[+]).*` to select the non-BGADD rows, and then use a second Regex to remove rows with two blocks of 4 numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, the number format/blocks is not consistent in actual use, but I believe I have answer based on the first part of your answer. Thank you for the help @Mako212

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I think I have answered my own question- thanks to the suggestion from @Mako212 which provided the first part I hadn't thought of yet.
The regex I have constructed finds lines that don't start with "BGADD" or "+" and then uses the same basis as the first regex in my question to match until it finds the next instance of "BGADD"

***What I think is the answer:***

```
^(?!BGADD|[+]).*$(\R|\z)(.*$(\R|\z))*?(?=BGADD)
```

***>>>Edited to simplify and capture last line of document:***

```
^(?!BGADD|[+])(.*$(\R|\z))+?(?=BGADD|\z)
```

***Output:***

```
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+          91016   91017   9
+          91024   91025   9
BGADD       1000100010011000
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+       19001006290010013900       
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+       19001006290010013900
BGADD       1000100010011000
+       30001002300010035000
+       19001006290010013900
BGADD       1000100010011000
```

Comment: It appears I cannot mark as an answer for 2 days, so I will do so then.

Comment: I think you could simplify a little further to `^(?!BGADD|[+])(.*$(\R|\z))*?(?=BGADD)` which removes the repeated `\R|\z` block, and instead just searches for the `.*$(\R|\z)` pattern multiple times.

Comment: Agreed! I actually just popped back to add a similar comment. I have refined it to `^(?!BGADD|[+])(.*$(\R|\z))+?(?=BGADD|\z)` which also includes the `\z` to get the last line of the document if need be.